# form submits url parameter instead of update

Tags: php, html, forms

This is probably a really stupid question, but I can't figure out why my code is doing this. I'm trying to do a simple recordset update and yet when I hit the submit button on the page, it will reload the page and in the url have multiple url parameters of the info from the form.

I have two forms in the whole document, one, the one I'm working with is supposed to change a variable in the database to the username of the user

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="Catch">
<input name="Horseid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $colname_WildHorse?>"/>
<input name="Owner" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $colname_HorseImage?>"/>
<input name="Catch" type="submit" value="Catch"/>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="Catch"/>
</form>
```

This is the one that returns all the url stuff after I hit the submit button. The second form is under it, and I want that one to display in the Url, which it does perfectly fine. Why is this one freaking out though?

URL produced:

```
http://localhost:8888/TheMeadow.php?Horseid=38&Owner=redlilac78&Catch=Catch&MM_update=Catch
```

This is the result code: I left out the style sheet since it's a lot

```
<title>The Meadow</title>
<style type="text/css">
//Left out style
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="Background">
<div id="Logo"><img src="Images/RR_Art/Website pages/Logo/Ropin' Ranch logo.gif" width="229" height="192" /></div>
<div id="Map"><a href="Map.php">Map</a></div>
<div id="Directories">Directories</div>
<div id="LogOut"><a href="/TheMeadow.php?doLogout=true&Horseid=42&amp;Owner=redlilac78&amp;Catch=Catch&amp;MM_update=Catch">Log out</a></div>
<div id="Note">
<form action="" method="get">
<p>


Welcome to the wild, where you can catch and search for wild horses! You can only catch one horse every two days so choose your horse wisely!         </p>
<div id="Name"><br> <br> <br>  <br>  <br>
<form name = "WildHorse" id = "WildHorse" onSubmit="TheMeadow.php?HorseId43">
<input type = "hidden" name = "HorseId" value = "43"/>
<input type = "submit" name = "" value = "Search" />

</form>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: what is the value of `$editFormAction`?

Comment: Please post an example of what the form looks like when fully rendered as HTML. I wonder if the `$editFormAction` variable is actually breaking the rest of it. An empty value for `$editFormAction` would post back to the same page, but not explain weirdness you see with the URL (which sounds more like a `GET` action than a `POST`)

Comment: Be cautious with your whitespace too. I see a few in there with space around `=` like `value =` instead of `value=`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski what do you mean by fully rendered in HTML, I fixed the white space problem. I don't think that the form is empty because underneath it I'm echoing the two values $colname_WildHorse and $colname_HorseImage and they both have a result of what I want.

Comment: I mean to copy/paste from the browser's page source after loading the form. So all the PHP values are fully substituted and rendered as HTML.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski http://localhost:8888/TheMeadow.php?Horseid=38&Owner=redlilac78&Catch=Catch&MM_update=Catch

Comment: LOL, we can't see your localhost bud.

Comment: So that's the URL it produces, but please edit above to show the HTML form.

Comment: @BigRabbit yeah I know, I can launch it on the real site if you really need to access the page.

Comment: No one here needs to see the real site, just copy and paste the code into your question as an edit.

Comment: What people are telling you is to after this problem, click with the right mouse button on the page rendered in the navigator and select "source code" item, then copy/paste the result on your question for us.

Comment: A we thought... it'empty... how do you calculate $editFormAction ? the problem is that whatever code you made to attribute the value to this variable came out empty.

Comment: Okay, so then I moved that form to outside of the if statement, and it worked, but thats weird because that if statement would have to be true for the button "Catch" to even display wouldn't it? @NelsonTeixeira

Comment: we can't be sure because you haven't show us the complete php code... that "if" you're talking about for example, we have not seen it. If you want futher assistance please use http://pastebin.com/ to post the entire php code.

Answer (score -1):

In your form action the problem is with `$editFormAction` in php , it is either empty or having the same files name due to which the form is being submitted to the same page.

Comment: @BigRabbit, then what do you think it is, please tell me.

Comment: @BigRabbit, you are welcome to do so :), but this simple problem and i know the reason for that problem. The form can submit to itself only when the action attribute is empty. That means that `$editFormAction` is either empty or has same file name.

Comment: @BigRabbit, did you read my answer before giving this example, i already told that page form action might contain same file's name.

Comment: What are you talking i do not understand, editing was done long ago before you started commenting on my answer :). Any how thanks for commenting on my answer. The last edit was to arrange the content properly.

Comment: For your info, i am also getting up votes. Thanks bye.